# How to Convert Number to Currency Format using WPF and C#.net

Tags: c#, wpf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert string value to decimal with thousand seperator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13834265/convert-string-value-to-decimal-with-thousand-seperator)

This might be a very simple question.

I want a Convert number to Currency Format.

Double number = 1000000.00;

Convert to

String Strnumber = 10,00,000.00;

Any Idea?..................

But it shows only number not a currency Name

Answer (score 1):

Use the `C`format specifier for currency.

```
Double number = 1000000.00;
String output = number.ToString("C2");
```

- [The Currency ("C") Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#CFormatString)

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/aBTmLI)

**Edit**: If you don't want a currency-symbol as commented you can use the overload of `ToString` with the `FormatProvider`. Then pass a custom [`NumberFormatInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.aspx) without symbol:

```
var culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
var mutableNfi = (NumberFormatInfo) culture.NumberFormat.Clone();
mutableNfi.CurrencySymbol = "";
String output = number.ToString("C2", mutableNfi);
```

Comment: `C8` will output `$1,000,000.00000000` ('$' = whatever the local currency symbol is). Did you mean `C2`?

Comment: @tobias86: Already corrected. But the number determines the number of decimal places. Even with C8 i get `€` as currency symbol here in ger (`1.000.000,00000000 €`).

Comment: How to remove currency name in front of the number? I want a just number not a currency name.

Comment: @DipakShinde: Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @DipakShinde: You might want to add a `Trim()` since i don't know how to remove the white-space between the (now omitted) currency-symbol and the value. Remember to accept an answer of your choice.

Comment: Yeah. I always accept answer of my choice. I just want an idea of my problem. And I got it.

Answer (score 0):

```
decimal value = 16325.62m;
string specifier;

specifier = "N";
Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", specifier, value.ToString(specifier));
// Displays:    N: 16,325.62
```

Answer (score 0):

From the required output it seems like you are using the indian number grouping system.

The following should provide you with the value formated in Lakh/Crore etc.

```
Double number = 1000000.00;
Console.WriteLine(String.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-IN"), "{0:C2}", number));
```

It should output

```
10,00,000.00
```

If you want to display the number without the currency symbol.  You can either reformat the number using `N` general number specifier.  The only issue to consider is how you would like the negative numbers displayed. eg,

```
Double number = 1000000.00;
Console.WriteLine(String.Format(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-IN"), "{0:N2}", number));
```

Or you can replace the currency symbol within the Number Format specifier. eg,

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-IN");
ci.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol = "";
Console.WriteLine(String.Format(ci, "{0:N2}", number));
```

Both should output

```
10,00,000.00
```

Comment: I show the number like Rs.10,00,000.00  but I want a number like 10,00,000.00

Comment: Use `N` instead of `C`.  eg, `String.Format(ci, "{0:N2}", number)`