# Convert string value to decimal with thousand separator?

Tags: c#

This might be a very simple question.
Suppose  text box show value 10,000.12 when user edits data by mistake he remove first two numbers like ,000.12 and using this textbox in the calculation then it gives an exception. I want a just validate text box.

For Example:
string str = ",100.12;"
Convert to
    decimal number =  100.12;

Any Idea?.

It shows only whole number when user remove any thousand separator.

Comment: Is the semi-colon *really* part of the string? Is there *really* a leading comma?

Comment: `decimal n = decimal.Parse(str.Replace(',', ''));` Not sure what you are trying to do anyway.

Comment: I think we need to better understand the input data that is possible. Your example input seems not to make any sense.

Comment: @Jonathan Wood: hi.. Suppose text box show value 10,000.00 when user edits data by mistake he remove first two numbers like , 000.00 and using this textbox in the calculation then it gives an exception. I want a just validate text box

Comment: Please just edit your question if you have additional information to add.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty messed up and I am not sure if all of you strings will look the same, but in case they do this might do the trick:

```
string str = ",0,100.12";
decimal number;
bool converted = decimal.TryParse(str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf(",") + 1), out number);
```

The variable `converted` will tell you whether or not your string was converted and you will not an exception.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question, you want to remove all characters that would prevent the parse routine from failing.

```
string str = ",0,100.12";

var modified = new StringBuilder();
foreach (char c in str)
{
    if (Char.IsDigit(c) || c == '.')
        modified.Append(c);
}

decimal number= decimal.Parse(modified.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string a = "100.12";
decimal b = Convert.ToDecimal(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = ",0,100.12;";
var newstr = Regex.Replace(str,@"[^\d\.]+","");
decimal d = decimal.Parse(newstr, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```